# Aiohttp logging me out but Requests not

Tags: python, asynchronous, aiohttp

I'm trying to migrate from my working Requests code that log me to youtube and scrape some data (I'm logging with previously saved cookies). This sync version works fine:

```
def login():
    headers = {'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br' ...}
    session.headers.update(headers)
    session.cookies.set(**mycookies)
    yt = session.get('https://www.youtube.com').text
    #generating some google-specific headers and jsons here
    tmp = session.post('https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/guide'\
    , headers=addit_headers, params={'key': innertube_key}, json= guide_payload)
```

guide request is important because every time you use youtube this post request allows you to use youtube services (like normally in browser). And everything works fine.

But when i'm attempting to to do same thing with aiohttp I receive guide json answer that tells me I'm logged out. Consider code below:

```
async def login(session):
    headers = {'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br' ...}
    async with session:
        async with session.get('https://www.youtube.com', headers= headers) as response:
        yt = await response.text()
        #generating google-specific headers and payload
        async with session.post('https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/guide', headers= headers,\
        params= {'key': innertube_key}, json = guide_payload) as response:
            tmp = await response.json()
```

And here's the trick. Guide request sends me json like I'm not logged in, maybe as if I was requesting it without requesting youtube doc earlier. Also if it's important I have one common session in main code:

```
async def set_up_session():
    return aiohttp.ClientSession(cookies = mycookies)
loop= asyncio.get_event_loop()
session = loop.run_until_complete(set_up_session())
loop.run_until_complete(login(session))
```

I am sure that when I'm requesting youtube main page it recognizes me because it sends back some info in doc such as "authorizedUserIndex", "DELEGATED_SESSION_ID" etc. This info wouldn't be sent if I don't provide my cookies.

Also after searching I have a hunch aiohttp can't handle redirects comparing to httpx or requests.
How to fix such ungateful code behaviour?

Comment: if you think it is problem with redirection then you should get response, check if status is `30X` and use new `URL`  from header to make another `GET` request.

Comment: do you really have to do it directly with HTML page? Can't you do it with `YouTube API`?

Comment: I can't use API since it has limits per google project neither get new url: when getting 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/guide' it only require innertube_key in url, a key that google sends to me in first doc answer. I only mentioned about redirects barely but I have no clue where is the problem